# How do I convert ASP.NET web pages to PDF dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, pdf

How do i convert asp.net pages to PDF dynamically, or at least convert dynamically generated picture to a pdf?
Thanks

Comment: Please. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching?

Among others, [this forum post](http://webforumz.com/net/2832-how-to-convert-html-page-to.htm) to which I was automagically redirected when searching on 'convert asp.net to pdf', seems to have quite a lot of suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Tutorial on using iTextSharp, http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article.aspx?ArticleID=80